# How to split a pandas dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data/training_Origional.csv', 'r') as f:

data2 = pd.read_csv(f)
#Col_Names = list(data2.columns.values)

# data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2.row.str.split('\t', 1).tolist(), columns=Col_Names)

print(data2)

# print(Col_Names)
```

I would like to read in a CSV file and then preform operations on the column values. When I run this code as is I get this kind of output:

```
0   100000\t138.47\t51.655\t97.827\t27.98\t0.9\t1...
1   100001\t160.937\t68.768\t103.235\t48.146\t-999...
2   100002\t-999\t162.172\t125.953\t35.635\t-999\t...
3   100003\t143.905\t81.417\t80.943\t0.414\t-999\t...
```

I would like to separate out the one column into many columns using the "\t" as a delimiter, but when I uncomment the commented lines of code, my code doesn't work. Is there a simpler way of "splitting" a column in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the separator for your "csv":

```
pd.read_csv('data/training_Origional.csv', sep='\t')
```