# Pandas: Splitting a column on a delimiter into multiple columns

Tags: pandas, csv, delimiter

This is my first post to StackOverflow and I hope I have absorbed some of the conventions in posting after reading and browsing and using the site some. I am having an issue in that I'd like to separate a csvfile which has all of the data in one column under 1 header into multiple columns for analyzing the data. My data looks like the following:

```
School ID,name,type,size,budget
0
0,Huang High School,District,2917,1910635
1
1,Figueroa High School,District,2949,1884411
2
2,Shelton High School,Charter,1761,1056600
3
3,Hernandez High School,District,4635,3022020
4
4,Griffin High School,Charter,1468,917500
```

and I want each of the words in the header (School ID, name, type, size etc.) to head their own column.

I tried the command
    pd.read_csv('../Desktop/schools_complete.csv', sep='\,')
as in this page

[How to split a pandas dataframe into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315288/how-to-split-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-columns)

but this had no effect and the data remained in one header. Please advise; any input would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Try without the slash: `df = pd.read_csv('../Desktop/schools_complete.csv', sep=',').dropna()`. Or just omit entirely to have pandas automatically determine the separator.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("schools_complete.csv").dropna()` worked for me.

Comment: Really? Still neither of these is working for me.  And, I realized I initially had tried it without the \ slash, with the slash gives me a funky error.

Comment: I still get a comma separated list and not one with the entries separated into columns.

Comment: Can you include the "funky error" into the question? That may help diagnose.

Comment: Error output looks like: 


C:\Users\ashok\Anaconda3\envs\Pythondata2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by re-downloading the original data file.  Thanks to those who provided suggestions.